# Nodejs sending to a specific user

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I already read a similar thread here about this but it didn't help me out.

Anyways, I am using v0.10.37.

### Server Code

```
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){});
server.listen(8082);

// socket.io
var socket = io.listen(server);
var clients = {};


socket.on('connection', function(client)
{

    client.on('setUserId',function(userid)
    {
        clients[userid[0]] = userid[1];
        console.log(clients);
    });

    client.on('message', function(msg)
    {

        if (msg.indexOf("notifications") != -1)
        {
            userid = msg.replace("notifications","");
            sessionid = clients[userid];
            //socket.clients[sessionid].send(msg);
        }

        else
        {
            console.log(msg);
            socket.send(msg);
        }
    })
});
```

The commented line with

```
socket.clients[sessionid].send(msg);
```

is the problem. I don't know what function to use to send for that specific `sessionid`. `sessionid` is valid, tested with `console.log`.

Comment: to send to a specific socket, use io.sockets(socketID).emit

Answer (score -1):

Try using `socket.emit`.
Also try referring the socket.io documentation.

Link:
http://devdocs.io/socketio/

Comment: Emit = send + custom event.  I see no examples with clientid in the documentation.

Comment: I figured it out, it was indeed emit.  The following did the trick :) .  socket.to(sessionid).emit('message',msg);